# Por que o inArray não detecta maiúsculas?

Tags: jquery, array

Não entendo porquê quando procuro por `PALAVRA` o [`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) do jQuery não a encontra. Mas se procuro por `palavra` dá positivo, quando na array está `PALAVRA`.

O primeiro teste que eu esperava positivo não funciona, por quê? No manual diz que a comparação de valores é estrita, o que significa nesse caso?

```
var titles = ['{EXTENSIONS}', '{dummy}'];

var title1 = "{EXTENSIONS}";
if( $.inArray( title1, titles ) ) {
    $('#txt1').text('No!'); // Não entra
}

var title2 = "{extensions}";
if( $.inArray( title2, titles ) ) {
    $('#txt2').text('Yes!'); // Entra
}

var title3 = "{dummy}";
if( $.inArray( title3, titles ) ) {
    $('#txt3').text('Yes!');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/1ubr2gsn/)

Comment: PS: O `in_array` do PHP é *case sensitive* e funciona como esperado. Será que é um caso pro [NaNNaNNaNNaNNaN, Batman](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9032856/1287812)?

Comment: Em jeito de brincadeira, podia mudar para MooTools :) E usar o [contains()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array:contains), onde o nome está mais de acordo com o que o código faz :)

Comment: O `~` na sua solução é golpe de mestre, valeu a pena ter perguntado sem ter lido o manual com atenção :) Na verdade, é um plugin pro StackEdit.io, tem que ser jQ, mas valeu a dica!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que o `inArray` não dá um *booleano* como o nome sugere. Ele dá o indice do elemento no array.

No seu primeiro caso dá `0`, daí o `if` falhar.

No segundo caso onde o `if` dá true, usando `"{extensions}"` com letra pequena, esse elemento não existe no array, daí o indice ser `-1`, e o `if` resolver `true`.

Se dermos uma olhada no código fonte:

```
inArray: function( elem, array ) {
    if ( array.indexOf ) {
        return array.indexOf( elem );
    }
    for ( var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( array[ i ] === elem ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
},
```

Pelos vistos a v[ersão mais moderna tem este código](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L353-L355) (em baixo) mas que no fundo é idêntico:

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    return arr == null ? -1 : indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
},
```

Assim no seu código pode substituir os `if`s por:

```
if( ~$.inArray(valor, array) ){
// ou
if($.inArray(valor, array) > -1){
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/1ubr2gsn/3/

Comment: Oh, dear, claro, tem que fazer `$.inArray( title1, titles ) > 0` então. Merci!

Comment: @brasofilo ou `if(~$.inArray( title1, titles )){` - http://jsfiddle.net/1ubr2gsn/3/

Comment: Olé!​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: `$.inArray( title1, titles ) > 0` está errado também, já que `0` é um índice válido, desta forma o correto seria `$.inArray( title1, titles ) > -1`, já que quando ele não encontra o retorno vai ser sempre `-1`

Comment: Óxênte, ficou sem aceite isto aqui? Inaceitável!

Comment: @brasofilo :) np, dei conta só agora também.